# How to remove a substring from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, substring

In SQL server, I want to remove a substring from the values in a varchar column, and if that results in the column being empty, I want the value to be NULL.

So given varchar STRING with values:

```
Foo
FooBar
Bar
```

If I remove the subtring 'Foo' I want the result to be:

```
NULL
Bar
Bar
```

My first attempt was:

```
UPDATE mytable SET string = REPLACE(string,'Foo',NULL)
```

which returns NULL for all values.

So I changed to:

```
UPDATE mytable SET string = REPLACE(string,'Foo','')
```

But the first record gets an empty string rather than being NULL.

So I resorted to:

```
UPDATE mytable SET string = NULLIF(REPLACE(string,'Foo',''),'')
```

which works, but I feel like there is probably a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with your code that is doing exactly what you stated you want it to do?

Comment: I think your way is fine :)

Comment: Agree with other commenters here: this is doing what you expect. This isn't a standard requirement in the same way that date comparisons are: there's not likely to be a "better way" than doing it the way you're doing it already. Perhaps you could use `CASE WHEN string = 'Foo' THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(string, 'Foo', '') END`, but at this point, you're just picking your poison.

Comment: Probably I was just getting tripped up on the difference between empty string and null in SQL server, and then after finding the NULLIF, wanted to make sure my approach wasn't horrifying.

Comment: Do you also want to remove FOO if it's on the "right" side of the string? For example TestFOO should be come Test? If not, then REPLACE won't work

Comment: Yes, removing FOO anywhere it appears.